# Display a series of colors sequencially with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer, colors

I need to display a series of RGB colors inside my ASP.NET web page. I was hoping to accomplish this using an ASP Update Panel but the update has to take place in sequence without the user intervention, every 4 or 5 seconds.

My initial JavaScript code looks like this :

```
document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,255)";
```

Problem is getting the next RGB color combination to display.
I experimented with a wait 'loop' found here in another post :

```
wait(7000); //7 seconds in milliseconds

function wait(ms) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while (end < start + ms) {
                end = new Date().getTime();
            }
        }
```

Problem is that, it does not work. I tried with :

```
document.getElementById('fondRGB').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,255)";
wait(7000);
document.getElementById('fondRGB').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(128,128,128)";
wait(7000);  
document.getElementById('fondRGB').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)";
```

but only the very first rgb color is ever honored?

Comment: Aaah.. Use `setInterval`

Comment: do NOT use a 'do-nothing' loop for timing. use  setInterval() (repeating) or setTimeout() (oneshot) instead.

Comment: The reason Rayon and Marc B are saying to not use your wait() function and to instead use setTimeout() or setInterval() is because both of those methods are asynchronous, which means that other actions can be performed while they are running. Your wait() function, however, is fully synchronous and will lock out the browser from handling clicks, keystrokes, events, etc. until the function is finished running. Javascript is single-threaded, so all synchronous code is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

running a blocking `while` loop in javascript is a really bad idea. There is only one thread so if you do that the user will not be able to interact with your application until your while loop is complete.

A better solution is to use `setTimeout` to run the timer asynchronously and call the callback when the timer is complete.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('fondRGB')

function wait(ms, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, ms)
}

wait(7000, function(){
  el.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,255)"
})

wait(14000, function(){
  el.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(128,128,128)"
})

wait(21000, function(){
  el.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,0,0)"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So even if that did work it wouldn't be what you want since the wait function is attempting to block the only execution thread which would just make the whole browser hang. The wait method you are looking for is called [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and it works a little different than you are probably used to.

setTimout lets you specify a function and an amount of milliseconds before it will execute that function so in your case if you want to accomplish changing the background color every 7 seconds you would probably do something like this:

```
var colors = ['rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(128,128,128)', 'rgb(0,0,0)'];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(color) {
        document.getElementById('fondRGB').style.backgroundColor = color;
    }.bind(null, colors[i]), i * 7000);
}
```

Sorry that the code got a little complex, look up closures if you are wondering why the .bind part is necessary (if you are not already familiar).